# What should happen when a generator function is assigned?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, generator, semantics, language-design

If I have a programming language with first class functions. What should the semantics be when a generator function is shared?

For example:

```
var f = function() { 
  foreach (i in 0..42)
     yield i;
}

int a = f(); // 0
int b = f(); // 1

// Assigning the generator function 
var g = f;

int c = g(); // ??
int d = f(); // ??
```

I can imagine three things:

1. c == 2, d == 3 meaning that the generator function is shared
2. c == 0, d == 2 meaning that a new generator function is created, with the values initialized
3. c == 2, d == 2 meaning that a new generator function is created by copying the current state of the generator

The best answer in my opinion, would provide the most compelling argument to do one mechanism or another. Often I find that prior art is the most persuasive argument.

Comment: And for bonus points, what about different threads?

Comment: Different threads is an independent issue. It also occurs even if you don't assign generators (assuming threads can access the same variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have reference semantics in your language, and assignment is usually reference assignment, then you want option 1.

This is what happens in Python, where generates *are* objects, and assignment *is* reference assignment (even though you invoke .next() to retrieve the next value, rather than "calling" the generator).

Here is a brief demonstration how this behaves in Python:

```
>>> def gen():
...   for i in range(42):
...     yield i
... 
>>> f = gen().next
>>> a = f()
>>> b = f()
>>> g = f
>>> c = g()
>>> d = f()
>>> a, b, c, d
(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: If editing to include a big block of code is too much, I'm sorry! I wanted it added and felt it was too little for an answer of its own.

Comment: The code looks right to me, so the edit is fine (although I find that setting f to the bound next method is too cute; I would rather share the generator, not the bound method).